# Where to set the visibility of Network Indicator with Redux?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

I have several actions in my application which fetches data from an API. I am setting a "loading"-attribute in my redux-store, if the action is fetching. Now I want to show a network indicator the app is fetching data.

I found a quick&dirty solution but I am sure, that this is not the way to do it:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { AppRegistry, StatusBar } from 'react-native';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import reducer from './app/reducers';

import App from './app/providers/App';

const createStoreWithMiddleware = applyMiddleware(thunk)(createStore);
const store = createStoreWithMiddleware(reducer);

class AppName extends Component {
    render() {

        store.subscribe(() => {
            if( 
                store.getState().dishes.loading
                || store.getState().deals.loading
            ) StatusBar.setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible(true);
            else StatusBar.setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible(false);
        });


        return (
          <Provider store={store}>
              <App />
          </Provider>
        );
    }
}

AppRegistry.registerComponent('AppName', () => AppName);
```

What is the correct way to hook such a listener?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid calling `StatusBar.setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible` too many times, you can watch the changes in your state using `componentWillReceiveProps` in your connected component.

```
import AppContainer from './containers/AppContainer';

class AppName extends Component {
    render() {        
        return (
          <Provider store={store}>
              <AppContainer />
          </Provider>
        );
    }
}
```

*containers/AppContainer.js*

```
import App from '../components/App.js';

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  loading: state.dishes.loading || state.deals.loading
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(App);
```

*components/App.js*

```
class App extends Component {

   componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
     if (!this.props.loading && nextProps.loading) {
       // Changing from `not loading` to `loading`
       StatusBar.setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible(true);
     } else if (this.props.loading && !nextProps.loading) {
       // Changing from `loading` to `not loading`
       StatusBar.setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible(false);
     }
   }

   // ...
}
```